# Run function right after asynchronous one

Tags: javascript

I want to store in `chrome.storage` ids. Using `INSERT_OR_REMOVE("blocked",12)` I am adding or removing `12` from database. The thing is that it is working asynchronous. What I want to do is to use `colorize` function right after. What should I do to archive that?

```
function INSERT_OR_REMOVE(table, id) {
    if (isNaN(id))
        return;

    var parsed = parseInt(id);

    chrome.storage.local.get(table, function (data) {
        if (data[table] == null)
            data[table] = [];

        if (!data[table].includes(id))
            data[table].push(id);
        else
            data[table].remByVal(id);

        chrome.storage.local.set(data);
    });
}

function colorize() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("blocked", function (data) {
        var buttons = $("div.base-btn").closest("table");
        for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { 
            var id = $(buttons[i]).attr("data-id");

            if (data["blocked"].includes(id))
                $(buttons[i]).parent().addClass('blocked');
            else
                $(buttons[i]).parent().removeClass('blocked');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Make `colorize` a callback of `.local.set` call?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome `StorageArea.set()` accepts a callback function which is run on success/failure. It is identical to the callback you passed to `chrome.storage.local.get(table, callbackFunction)`

You just need to add `colorize` as the callback to be run on completing set:

```
chrome.storage.local.set(data, colorize)
```